# How to save login details of different kinds of users into one table

Tags: mysql, authentication, save, create-table

I have created 2 separate tables for admins and users in my database. I want to save user and admin login details (ip address, user_agent, connection time etc) into one table. Is the only solution to create two fields one for admin ids and other for user ids in this table (like below)?

```
CREATE TABLE login_detail (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    admin_id int,
    user_id int,
    ip_address ...
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (admin_id) REFERENCES admin(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
)
```

If an administrator logs in, his id will be stored in `admin_id` and `user_id` will be empty. If a user logs in, his id will be stored in `user_id` and `admin_id` will be empty. What do you suggest (generally)?

Comment: Why not have a single column for the user/admin id and then a bit field indicating if the users was an admin or user?

Comment: I need a foreign key to save valid ids, or I think it is good to use a FK in this situation. Since there can only one FK on a field, I need a separate field for each FK.

Comment: Aah, you mean user and admin table... I separate them so there would be no confusion. Someone else who like to add some code may forget that level check and user may do admin operations.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that ermagana understood you were converting those two tables into one table, not accessing those two tables through the new, third table.  At least, that is what I assumed until I saw your response. Am I correct?  If so...

In general, there is really no reason why this wouldn't all be in one table with a bit-flag indicating admin authority, as ermagana responded.  I believe that would be the most common implementation, though certainly not the only option.

Your implementation using three tables, as I understand it, will require extra coding and certainly more database activity.  You will need to check if the user is a user and, if not, then check if the user is an admin.  Also, how are you going to ensure that the same user isn't in both tables without extra coding and database activity?  At least how I understand it, it appears inefficient and error-prone.

Perhaps I don't understand it at all.  If so, please clarify.

Comment: You are right, multiple tables are bad... You can check third comment above for the reason :/

Comment: That is another reason in addition to the several I provided.  What is it that you intend to do?  Are you combining the tables.